# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reply' of null

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

i want make a button command but a have this problem:

```
await msgInt.reply({
             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reply' of null
```

idk why happened this, someone can explain me why that's happened?

this is my code (wrote with typescript):

```
import { Interaction, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } from "discord.js";
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";

export default {
    category: "Testing",
    description: "Interazione pulsante",

    callback: async ({ interaction: msgInt, channel }) => {
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId("yes")
                .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                .setLabel("Conferma")
            )

            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId("no")
                    .setStyle("DANGER")
                    .setLabel("Nega")
            )
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription("**SICURO DI PROCEDERE?**")
                .setAuthor("clicca su un pulsante per rispondere.")
                .setColor("ORANGE")
        
        await msgInt.reply({
            content: "sicuro di procedere?",
            embeds: [embed],
            components: [row],
        })
    }
} as ICommand
```

Comment: How do you run this? Like `command.callback(...)`

Comment: this is a command handler, I run that with ts-node